# The Strangely Clairvoyant Hobo

Tags: situation

One day, I was waiting to get on the subway. I was eating the apple I always have for breakfast, and I decided to sit next to a homeless man on the bench. We saw a rather... rotund man walk by us, to which the hobo muttered, "Pig."

I didn't give it a second thought, except how rude the comment was. Another man walked past, this time tall and in a business suit. As he walked past, the hobo said "Human." and I thought nothing of this remark, other than how obviously he was, in fact, human. I soon after boarded the train for work.

The next day, the hobo was still there. Today, as I watched from a distance, he was at it again. Several people walked past him: a skinny woman, a muscular man, and an old lady, to which he respectively muttered "Soup", "Pork", and "Cookie". Odd, I thought, considering none of them was a cookie. Throughout my day, I couldn't stop thinking about this weird hobo in the subway.

Over the next few days, I kept observing him. He continued this odd behavior. "Bread", "Carrot", "Milk", "Rabbit", and other utterances as people walked past. So the next day, I walked by the homeless man again and he muttered, "Apple."

I finally recognized what this hobo was doing... and after thinking on it for a little bit, remembered something and was stricken with horror.

What was this hobo's ability? What had me so disturbed?

Comment: Your brainteaser doesn't make sense: "Over the **next few days**, I kept observing him. He continued this odd behavior. 'Bread', 'Carrot', 'Milk', 'Rabbit', and other utterances as people walked past. **So the next day**, I walked by the homeless man again and he muttered, 'Apple.'"

Comment: The next day. After those few days. Makes sense to me.

Comment: This is a creepypasta too. [The Man Behind The Train Station](http://creepypasta.wikia.com/wiki/The_Man_Behind_the_Train_Station)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> He was listing what people had eaten (at some point in time) and had said "human" at one point.  That meant on the first day he had seen a cannibal.

Comment: I missed that crucial "human" remark - as though to imply that somebody was a cannibal :p +1

Comment: so if tis is right, what is the difference between pig and pork? MMAAYYBBEE he was having an off day?

Comment: Maybe he's never eaten bacon. :D

Comment: I prefer to think that the man merely chews his nails.

Answer (score 4):

He knew what you had for breakfast. He rummages through the rubbish bins and has become acquainted with everybody's eating habit.

Comment: dang, same time

Comment: Yes, but you caught the cannibal thing - obviously I can't use that now thank you very much