# Riddle... I am like a dear halo

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

I am like a dear halo,
Plucked from a rainbow,
A tight noose brings me to life,
With the repeated stab of a knife,  
Old grief of the elephants,
Holy like the elements,
I penetrate a scar of my soft master,
I elude many, you better run faster.

Comment: @d'alar'cop - Is it OK to remove spoilertags in our answers if they're wrong? (Because certain people sneak around downvoting answers with too much spoilertagging!)

Comment: @randal'thor Yes, sure it is. Good idea actually

Comment: I will have to look up some wirds first :)

Comment: With the brilliant answers below, I do hope the intended answer is really, really good, because there is some tough competition down there!

Comment: @randal'thor Even if the answers aren't what d'alar'cop is going for, I plan to upvote the ones that I really like. There's some truly thought provoking answers down there.

Comment: @corsiKa lol. yes, _amazing_ line-up below I agree. I'll pick what matches the clues best (with regards to the explanations too) :)

Comment: Could it be one of the colours of the rainbow??

Comment: @randal'thor If you can make one of them fit all the clues somehow then write it up..

Comment: So many directions in one riddle.  A 'dear halo' suggests an expensive ring - a wedding ring, that'll cost and cost and cost.  A noose bringing life suggests a tourniquet.  Stabbing repeatedly with a knife suggests a microwave meal.  Old grief of elephants?  A mouse.  Holy like elements, is cheese an element?  Swiss cheese...  Gawd knows...

Comment: @GrimmTheOpiner Yes, it's very cryptic. But a riddle that's hard to solve and veiled in such ways is much more interesting than a dead easy riddle solved in 10 seconds isn't it?

Comment: I hope you don't mind if I put all your hints in one place. Smaller than 'red' or 'pain', not as small as 'blood', something 'grounded' and close to 'ivory' (is 'cyanide' a clue or just something between you and avigrail?)

Comment: @randal'thor cyanide is an inside joke... his riddles are painful

Comment: @randal'thor http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4877/riddle-i-am-like-a-dear-halo/4904#comment14407_4904

Comment: @randal'thor the 4 classical elements

Comment: @randal'thor what about the rest of the clues?

Comment: OK, nice one there!

Comment: @avigrail the best part is.. I don't _think_ people will be lynching me after it's all over :p (which I was worried about at some stage)

Comment: No they wont. It is really fitting!

Comment: @avigrail well, have you got it? :p it might be right under your nose you know...

Comment: Well, I said it's really fitting ;) but I'm knob sure about it.

Comment: I think I know the answer but do not have enough rep to post it D:

Comment: @user3334690 I am very sorry my friend :(

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is a:

> button

Finally enough clues to guess it ;)

Relevant details:

I am like a dear halo,

> Something precious and circular

Plucked from a rainbow,

> In any color

A tight noose brings me to life,

> The eye of a needle/needle and thread

With the repeated stab of a knife,

> knife = needle

Old grief of the elephants,

> ivory buttons?

Holy like the elements,

> Has 4 holes like the 4 elements (earth air fire water)

I penetrate a scar of my soft master,

> not sure why it's a scar, but sewn on...

I elude many, you better run faster.

> Buttons often get lost

Comment: It was more than a hint actually :D

Comment: I was working on it, you stomped on my edit :p

Comment: _I penetrate a scar of my soft master_ refers to the button hole in the shirt.

Answer (score 6):

I'm thinking of:

> Water.
>
> *I'm like a dear halo*, 
> *Plucked from a rainbow*: Rainbows and water always come together, and the rain seems like to *fall* (plucked) from the rainbow and form a wet *halo* to the portion of land where its raining.
>
> *A tight noose brings me to life, With the repeated stab of a knife*: drop by drop (knife stabs) a tiny hole (noose) is made, which can then lead to an opening through which water can pass.
>
> *Old grief of the elephants, Holy like the elements*: Stones can be considered elephants here: grey, huge and long living. Their grief is that tiny drop that continues to fall on them, filling them with sorrow and pain. Also, water is one of the elements, but the only one that can be *holy*.
>
> *I penetrate a scar of my soft master, I elude many, you better run faster.*: Here the master is our planet earth. Water makes its way trough it leaving a scar on it. When a dam its built, everyone thinks that it will resist. When it does not, well, run.

Comment: @Narmer - You got out of the party safely, then? http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4751/the-security-to-the-party-part-31

Comment: @d'alar'cop thanks to this question I have just discovered a fantastic optical phenomena (and all it's derivates) called [Halo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halo_%28optical_phenomenon%29). This is why I love SE :D (PS: if this is a spoiler I'll remove it asap)

Answer (score 4):

A hunch tells me it is

> the different forms of Gold

I cannot make sense of all the lines, but it seems to match some fairly well

I am like a dear halo,

> religious christian imagery used gold foil to depict the "holy radiation"

Plucked from a rainbow,

> Leprechauns in Irish folk tales are said to leave a pot of gold at the end of a rainbow

A tight noose brings me to life,
With the repeated stab of a knife,

> could be a reference to the rubber that flows out of the gum trees when you cut them

Old grief of the elephants,

> elephants have been hunted for their tusk which is also called white gold

Holy like the elements,
I penetrate a scar of my soft master,

> fossil oil is the "black gold" that flows out of the ground

I elude many, you better run faster.

> Pyrite/fool's gold could be the one that eludes all

Comment: look at all comments on the answers.

Answer (score 4):

This sounds for me like a *tattoo*:

> I am like a dear halo,

Dear to the person who has the tattoo.

> Plucked from a rainbow,

Tattoos may use inks of different colors.

> A tight noose brings me to life,
>   With the repeated stab of a knife,

This is the noose of the nail that injects the ink by stabbing into the skin.

> Old grief of the elephants,
>   Holy like the elements,

Not really sure about this... elephants presumably refers to the nooses mentioned before.

> I penetrate a scar of my soft master,

A tattoo penetrates the skin of the one who decides to have it.

> I elude many, you better run faster.

Not sure either.

Answer (score 3):

Could it be **death**?

I can't make this fit with all the lines, but:

"*A tight noose brings me to life*" - if someone is hanged, death appears on the scene ('comes to life'?). Similarly if someone receives "*the repeated stab of a knife*".

"*Old grief of the elephants*" - the famous elephant 'graveyards' (or is this irrelephant?)

"*I elude many, you better run faster*" - people might try to run from death, but can never run fast enough.

Probably not...

Comment: I don't think death eludes many people.

Comment: @GrimmTheOpiner - No, and it doesn't even get eluded by many! Oh well.

Answer (score 3):

is it

> light

reasoning for it

> A break in the clouds. rainbow is made from it refracting. light at the end of the tunnel from dying. many cuts could create a whole in something for light to come through. elephant legend were to be known wonder off and die without anything seeing. only the light reflected could carry this image. Holy light scar could be any imperfection ins a solid that makes it translucent. many people are blind and light is fast so you have to run really fast if you can see but want to escape it.

so that or maybe it's

> ghost

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like

> a thunder

I am like a dear halo,
Plucked from a rainbow,

> thunders are bright and glorious

A tight noose brings me to life,

> the form of the thunder resembles a noose

With the repeated stab of a knife,

> probably the repeating sound of many rain drops

Old grief of the elephants,

> probably the sound of a comming thunder storm

Holy like the elements,

> thunders are associated with god's anger

I penetrate a scar of my soft master,

> the scar could be the thunder itself in the cloudy sky (that's why soft)

I elude many, you better run faster.

> the people run and try to find shelter when thunder storm is comming

EDIT:

could it be

> a painting? or icon?

Comment: you know, I won't give up.. close enough is not good enough :P

Answer (score 3):

Third try: **pain**.

Seems to fit all but the first two lines.

"*A tight noose brings me to life,

 With the repeated stab of a knife, 

 Old grief of the elephants*"

A noose, stabbing, and grief are all similar to it.

"Holy like the elements" - I'm sure I remember some quote about pain being holy. Not so sure about the elements.

"*I penetrate a scar of my soft master*" - scars, same theme.

"*I elude many, you better run faster.*" - anaesthetic?

Answer (score 2):

Is it

> Planetary ring? I.e. the rings of saturn specifically?

I am like a dear halo,
Plucked from a rainbow,

> Is halo shaped, and multi-colored as a rainbow

A tight noose brings me to life,
With the repeated stab of a knife,

> Gravity is the tight noose, bringing the frozen ice together in this shape

Old grief of the elephants,

> Planetary rings are made mostly of water, as elephant tears.

Holy like the elements,

> We can't see planetary rings directly from earth?

I penetrate a scar of my soft master,

> The ring could be composed of pieces of the planet, since original formation is unknown.

I elude many, you better run faster.

> Possibly another reference to their invisibility to the naked eye?

Comment: I really love all these interpretations. I'll see what fits the clues best at some point :)

Comment: look at all comments on the answers.

Answer (score 2):

The colour **red**.

"*I am like a dear halo*" - 'dear' is an anagram of 'read', which is a homophone of 'red'.

"*Plucked from a rainbow*" is pretty self-explanatory.

"*A tight noose brings me to life*" - does a person's face go red when they're hanged?

"*With the repeated stab of a knife*" - blood-red.

"*Old grief of the elephants*" - not so sure about this one.

"*Holy like the elements*" - cardinals in the Catholic Church wear red.

"*I penetrate a scar of my soft master*" - scar tissue is red.

"*I elude many, you better run faster*" - again, I can't make this one fit.

Comment: @d'alar'cop - Now I'm thinking of particle physics! "Holy like the elements" - an atom of any element has a certain structure, with holes in it maybe? Am I on another wrong track here?

Answer (score 2):

are you

> Blood

halo

> blood cells are circular

rainbow

> red

noose, knife, elephants

> blood running or surfacing based on bruising.

holy

> blood to wine. many other religious references of blood

scar

> recent scars can bleed during the healing process.

elude

> many people seek blood transfusions but can't get them?

better run faster

> blood flowing from a bag or flowing out of the body

Comment: Same sort of theme as my answers. We're covering a lot of grim and gruesome possibilities between us!

Answer (score 2):

How about

> Thread?

I am like a dear halo,
Plucked from a rainbow,

> Thread can be any color, and is wound in a spool.

A tight noose brings me to life,
With the repeated stab of a knife,

> You have to tie a knot through the needle to sow

Old grief of the elephants,

> Elephants bury their dead, a needle must bury the thread under other layers of thread to weave anything.

Holy like the elements,HOLEY. HOW MANY ELEMENTS?

> Four classical elements, four directions you sow in.

I penetrate a scar of my soft master,

> Each place a thread is sown, before there was a hole or space.

I elude many, you better run faster. IT IS EASILY LOST

> If the thread is not attached to a needle, or becomes removed while weaving, it is difficult to find.

Comment: you are the new closest... combine with old closest (avigrail - 1st revision)

Comment: Meaning his guess of ice? Or Jesus?

Comment: His guess of Ivory...

Answer (score 2):

how about

> a necklace? They were made of ivory in early days and are held together by a string / noose?

Comment: not bad at all... quite close really...

Comment: maybe it is just a part of it: the leather thong?

Comment: No. Change object a bit... but same vein

Comment: I totally get why your riddles are so hard. The only other thing related I can think of at the moment is an armlet ... but you said no wild guessing *argh*

well no, that seems to be the wrong english word. This must be so much easier as a native english speaker

Comment: If you're doing this without being a native speaker then you deserve a medal!

Comment: haha I want my medal! Honestly I am looking up so many words in a dictionary ;)

Bracelet is the word I was looking for

Comment: ok, wild guess: compass dial / wind rose

Comment: No guessing :p and no

Answer (score 1):

> a needle ? easily lost, stabs repeatidly, uses threads of any color, used to be made of ivory, used to sow back wounds and leaves scar. I don't see what the elements have to do with this, though.

Comment: as in the eastern medicinal technique?

Comment: `holey` works, but the number of elements, I don't see what to do with that, except http://www.answerswithacupuncture.com/4needle.htm

Comment: Now you got holey and 4. Need something else?