# A Creepy Birthday Party

Tags: lateral-thinking, situation, mystery

A little girl was invited to her friend's birthday party. After blowing out the candles and eating the cake, the children went out to play in the garden. The little girl's mother stayed in the kitchen talking to the other adults. They could hear the kids screaming and shouting as they played outside. Soon the little girl came running in the house. "There she is", said her mother. "It's her birthday next month. Tell everyone how old you are going to be" .

The little girl smiled and held up 4 fingers. All of the adults stared in horror.

Why was everyone staring at horror?

Comment: Hello @Anonymous, This question is going to invite so many speculative answers. Some gory answers too. Please consider this, This may get flagged

Comment: This is actually one of the famous horror puzzles and this has one correct solution using logic. Too unfortunate if this is not suitable in PSE .

Comment: Wow, this has already gathered more haters than I expected. Although the solution is macabre I kinda thought it would be received more similarly to [this 'classic' riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/3739/60644). Maybe the riddling climate has now changed... Interesting.

Comment: this is ... creepy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Surely everybody is staring in horror because:

> the 4 fingers which the girl holds up *are not hers*, and furthermore *are no longer attached to their original owner* (either as individual fingers or as part of the 4-fingers-and-1-thumb of a complete severed hand). It turns out all that 'screaming and shouting' may not have been as carefree and innocent as it originally seemed...

Comment: Really Close, what does $4$ mean here? Why not $3$ or $5$?

Comment: @Anonymous you've already accepted the answer, so now would you tell us why 4, for the sake of curiosity?

Comment: Because this is correct, and there is no point not doing it.