# Albatross Soup Riddle?

Tags: riddle, wordplay

A man was deserted on an island with his friends. Food were running low, but fortunately they managed to survive because one of them made some "albatross soup". After a few days, he was rescued by a ship and returned home safely.

One day, he walks into an establishment and got some albatrosses. However, contrary to how this last sentence usually tends to go, **he left happily without killing himself**, breaking literally every single possible conventions and tropes that are associated with this particular genre of exotic-animal-soup-based riddles in a handful of fell swoop.

**What happened?**

---

Attribution : I wrote this out of spite

Comment: Not knowing the context of the original riddle, or how the soup trope is supposed to go, this seems quite grim.

Comment: Albatross Soup is considered a classic "black stories" --- a type of riddle that opens with a short premise, usually involving death, and solvers askes binary questions to gain more information, eventually solving the mystery. And yes, it is about as grim as you think it is.

Comment: @Auribouros [This is a version of the original riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3739/the-old-man-doesnt-like-seagull-meat)

Comment: Turns out I did know about this, it seems the version I heard wasn't seagull, or sea-bird related.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps

> The establishment he walked into was a golf course. He scored several [albatrosses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Par_(score)#Albatross), which are an extremely rare achievement in golf.

Comment: Great find! So rare that I've never heard of it.

Answer (score 1):

Paying attention to what has not been stated:

> The man *walked into an establishment and got some albatrosses*.
>  He didn't get *albatross soup*.
>  He left happy because he successfully purchased (or maybe borrowed - we don't know) the albatrosses he wanted.
>
>  Maybe later he'll have a chance to make some "albatross soup" and reminisce about his time on the island and the friends he ate

> with.

> Definitely *with*.
>  The *with* is important